# Finding the current trough resistor in a closed mesh

Tags: voltage, current, thevenin, norton, mesh-analysis

In a closed mesh we have:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcMkZQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

> The question is to determine the current through the 2nd resistor \$\text{I}_x\$.

---

**My work**:

I think of two methodes:

1. Because the currents that flow into a node must add up to zero, we know that:

$$\text{I}_{\text{R}_1}+\text{I}_x=0=10\cdot10^{-3}+\text{I}_x\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\text{I}_x=-10\cdot10^{-3}\space\text{A}\tag1$$

2. The voltage across the two resistors must add up to \$10+\left(-5\right)=5\space\text{V}\$, and I lose \$10\cdot10^{-3}\cdot1000=10\space\text{V}\$ across \$\text{R}_1\$ so the thing I've left is \$5-10=-5\space\text{V}\$, so \$\text{I}_x=-\frac{-5}{1000}=\frac{1}{200}=5\space\text{mA}\$

Which of my methods is right?

Comment: Your question is confusing. Are there other components connected where your wires extend to the edge of the schematic?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson No it is given like I've drawn it, I think it is also confusing

Comment: 5 mA is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be currents entering/leaving the nodes via the spurs. This doesn't matter, you don't need to find these, just solve the isolated mesh with the information given.

1. \$\small R_2\$ has \$\small 10\: V\$ across it, with + on the left and - on the right.
2. The \$\small 5\:V\$ source has + on the right and - on the left, since its voltage is -5V.
3. The voltage across \$\small R_2\$ is \$\small I_x R_2\$ with + at the bottom and - at the top.

Now you can apply KVL to find \$\small I_x\$.

Don't expect KCL to work for this mesh - you have no way of knowing what currents are flowing through the spurs.

You have the correct answer: \$\small I_x = 5\:mA\$

Comment: Nicely explained and helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Neither of your answers is correct. If \$I_x\$ is -10mA then the total voltage drop across the two resistors is 20V and KVL is violated. If \$I_x\$ is 5mA then KCL is violated at the junction between the two resistors.

Your problem is nonsensical **as shown**.

Comment: There are currents entering through the other 'spurs'. KVL on the loop means the 10V source and 10V across R1 cancel; and the 5V source must be balanced by 5 mA through R2

Comment: @Chu Then the OP's answer to my first comment above is invalid. I specifically asked if there were other components and the OP said No. If there are no other components there can be no other currents through the "spurs".

Comment: Clearly, this is an academic exercise in using the available information to calculate an unknown current. It doesn't matter what's happening at the nodes, there must be currents entering and exiting at the nodes because KCL is not satisfied for the loop. Just apply KVL to the loop and there is only one unknown.

Comment: @Chu Of course it is an academic exercise, but it is a wasted effort if the OP does not understand that there **must** be other components connected to the given circuit.